# Maria DB ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, mariadb

i can't access to maria db.

I had tried to log in by using this command

```
Mysql -uroot -p
```

to access maria db, it didn't work out.

so i tried to log in by using sudo command, it still dosen't work out. what should i do?

Comment: even if i use sudo command, i see this error 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''